# How to get the finalized text after resolving co-references using StandfordNLP

Tags: java, nlp, stanford-nlp

Hi I just started learning NLP and chose Stanford api to do all my required tasks. I am able to do POS and NER tasks but I am stuck with co-reference resolution. I am even able to get the 'corefChaingraph' and able to print all the representative mention and corresponding mentions to console. But, I really would like to know how to get the finalized text after resolving the co-references. Can some one help me regarding this?

example:
Input sentence:
John Smith talks about the EU. He likes the family of nations.

Expected ouput:
John Smith talks about the EU. **John Smith** likes the family of nations.

Answer (score 0):

It depends a lot on what approach you take. I personally would try and solve this looking at what role a word plays in a sentence and what is the context carried forward. Based on the POS tags, try and map subject-verb-object model. Once you have subject and objects identified you can build a simple context carry forward rule system to achieve what you want.

e.g.

Based on the tags below:

```
[('John', 'NNP'), ('Smith', 'NNP'), ('talks', 'VBZ'), ('about', 'IN'), ('the', 'DT'), ('EU.', 'NNP'), ('He', 'NNP'), ('likes', 'VBZ'), ('the', 'DT'), ('family', 'NN'), ('of', 'IN'), ('nations', 'NNS'), ('.', '.')]
```

You can create chunks:

```
[['noun_type', 'John', 'Smith'], ['verb_type', 'talks'], ['in_type', 'about'], ['noun_type', 'the', 'EU']]

[['noun_type', 'He'], ['verb_type', 'likes'], ['noun_type', 'the', 'family'], ['in_type', 'of'], ['noun_type', 'nations']]
```

Once you have these chunks, parse them left to right putting them in `Subject-Verb-Object` form.

Now based on this, you know what is the context carry forward.

e.g.: "He" means the subject is getting carry forward. "It" means the object (this is a very basic example. You can build a robust rule based systems for patterns.) I have tried many approaches in past and this one gave me best results.

I hope I helped.

Comment: Actually, my real intention is to make triplets as Subject Predicate Oject from a paragraph. I believe that, in order to do that I need to resolve the co references first. But it seems your approach is completely in an opposite direction. Could you please share any code samples you have to make me clear on this?

Comment: Few questions before we get into it. Is your text well formed? Also, what are the approaches that you have tried out? Also are you looking at just the predicate or detailed object + other references in a sentence?

Comment: Yes text is well formed.I want to make RDF triples from the text.I tried the following approches
.POS tagging, Entity Extraction Using Stanford
.Parse tree formation using Stanford
.Now I am trying to resolve co references so that I can form parse trees from the co reference resolved text and extract triples then I will convert them to RDF triples...

Answer (score 0):

In my experience that problem you are trying to solve is not completely solved but there are many people working on it. I tried **"karaka"** approach. Not just to get subject-verb-object but also the other references from sentence.

Here is how I approached a problem:

```
step 1: Detect the voice of the sentence. 


Step 2: For active voice, parse a POS tagged sentence from left to right to get 
subject-verb-object (It will be always in that form for active voice). For passive voice look for "by" and take the next noun as a subject.
```

Looking at your example:

In both the sentences you have Noun-Verb-In-Noun structure. Which you can easily parse as first noun is subject then verb then IN (about is indicative to object) and then noun again. From there rules: John Smith is subject, Talks is action and EU is object.

Karaka theory in linguistic will also help you with other roles.

E.g.: `John Smith talks about EU in Paris.`

Here when you enouter in (IN tag) Paris (NNP tag) you can have a rule that tells you "in/on/around/inside/outside" are locative references.

Similarly "with/without" and instrumentative "for" is dative.

I basically trust this deep parsing and rule systems when I have to deal with a single word and the rule it plays in a sentence.

I have good amount of accuracy with this approach.